Next.js build error: Unsupported node type "ConditionalExpression" at "revalidate"
I'm encountering an error when running npm run build in my Next.js project:
⨯ Next.js can't recognize the exported `config` field in route "/dashboard/page":
Unsupported node type "ConditionalExpression" at "revalidate". 
Read More - https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-page-config

I don't have a config field in the /dashboard/page file. I tried deleting the node_modules directory and reinstalling the dependencies, but it didn't resolve the issue.
Here's what I've tried so far:

Deleted node_modules and reinstalled dependencies.
Checked for any config export in the /dashboard/page file.

Has anyone encountered this issue before or have any suggestions on how to fix it?
Here is the file content:
import prisma from "@/lib/db";
import CategoriesDashboardComponent from "./CategoryDashboardComponent";

const CategoriesDashboard = async () => {
  const data = await prisma.category.findMany({
    orderBy: {
      name: "asc",
    },
  });

  return (
    <div className="container p-4">
      <CategoriesDashboardComponent initialData={data} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default CategoriesDashboard;

Additional Information:

Next.js version: 15.0.3
Node.js version: v20.11.0
Operating System: Windows 11

Thank you in advance for your help!
